# Convert tree to list

Tags: recursion, tree, f#, f#-interactive

How can I convert a tree to a list:
So far I have the following code but its giving several issues:

```
type 'a tree = Lf | Br of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree;;

let rec elementRight xs = function
  | LF ->false
  | Br(m,t1,t2) -> if elementRight xs t1 = false then t1::xs else element xs t1;; //cannot find element
let rec elementLeft xs = function
  | LF ->false
  | Br(m,t1,t2) -> if elementLeft xs t2 = false then t2::xs else element xs t2 ;; //cannot find element
let rec element xs = function
  | LF ->[]
  | Br(m,t1,t2) -> xs::(elementRight xs t1)::(elementRight xs t2)::(elementLeft xs t1)::(elementLeft xs t2);;
```

Comment: Can you tell us what issues?

Comment: Issues
1. on t2::xs and t1::xs the expression expected is bool and has 'a list
2. on element xs t2 ;; cannot find element

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your code:

1. You shouldn't have `;;` at the end of lines (I'm guessing this means you're copy and pasting into the repl, you should really use an fsx file instead and use "send to repl").
2. This: `| LF ->false` is returning a bool, while this: `| Br(m,t1,t2) -> if elementRight xs t1 = false then t1::xs else element xs t1` is returning an `'a list`.  An expression can only have one type, so returning two is a compile error.  I'm guessing what you really are meaning to do is have the leaf return `[]` and then check for empty list in your branch case something like this:

```
let rec elementRight xs = function
  | LF ->[]
  | Br(m,t1,t2) -> if elementRight xs t1 = List.empty then t1::xs else element xs t1
```

3 . when using mutually recursive functions you need to use the `and` keyword for all declarations but the first like this:

```
let rec elementRight xs = function
  ...
and elementLeft xs = function
  ...
and element xs = function
  ...
```

Comment: It appears you also have a logic error in the `Br` case of `element`, but I'll let you figure that one out.

Comment: Hint: each function returns a list and using `::` on two lists will give you a list of lists.