# Parsing expression tree into nested lists

Tags: f#, expression-trees

I'm relatively new to F# and am really having a real struggle with parsing an expression tree, which contains nested lists.  From bits and pieces on the web I have cobbled together the following.

My standard type is defined:

```
type Return = 
    | Real of float
    | Func of string * Return list
```

I make a function call to an external application, which returns something like:

```
val out : Return =
    Func
        ("List",
             [Func ("List",[Real 1.0; Real 2.0; Real 3.0]);
              Func ("List",[Real 1.0; Real 2.0; Real 3.0]);
              Func ("List",[Real 1.0; Real 2.0; Real 3.0])])
```

and which I'm needing to parse into

```
[ [1.0; 2.0; 3.0] ; [1.0; 2.0; 3.0] ; [1.0; 2.0; 3.0] ]
```

My initial naive thought was along the lines of

```
let rec parse data =
    match data with
    | Real(y) -> y
    | Func("List", x) -> x |> List.map parse 
    | _ -> failwithf "Unrecognised"
```

but it's complaining about the type differences, which I now understand.

My second thought is to maybe use some recursive List.fold (as I can fold over the list of Reals and get the inner lists, but can't figure out how to generalise it into a recursive function without the compiler complaining out type).  Beyond my current intellectual fire-power.

My third thought is that maybe the return I get from the external application is making this too difficult, as there is no indication in the tuple fst about what is in the tuple snd, apart from the fact it is a "list of something"?

There is this: [Convert tree to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308972/convert-tree-to-list) but it's as cryptic as the solutions I'm trying tbh.

Any pointers as to which avenue I pursue would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the type of the object you want your `parse` function to return?

If your desired output is `[ [1.0; 2.0; 3.0] ; [1.0; 2.0; 3.0] ; [1.0; 2.0; 3.0] ]`, it appears that what you want to return is neither a `float list` nor a `float list list`, but rather an *arbitrarily nested list* of `float`.

But that doesn't exist as a standard type, and you'll need to define it yourself as a recursive discriminated union (we'll make it generic for good practice):

```
type NestedList<'a> = 
    | Single of 'a
    | Collection of NestedList<'a> list
```

Well look at that! It's just a thin reskin over your original `Return` type. That's because the original type is pretty much already a standard nested list implementation, except for the `"List"` label thing.

The `parse` function then has almost no real work left to do:

```
let rec parse = function
    | Real y ->  Single y
    | Func ("List", returns) -> Collection (returns |> List.map parse)
    | Func (l, _) -> failwithf "Unrecognised label %s" l
```

Comment: That's great thanks.  I'm clearly still thinking about types in too loose a way, but this gives me the structure I need.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is good to annotate the function you are implementing. Then it becomes explicit of what you are trying to do:

```
type Return = 
    | Real of float
    | Func of string * Return list

let rec parse (data : Return) : float list =
    match data with
    | Real y ->  [ y ]
    | Func (_, returns) -> returns |> List.collect parse
    | _ -> failwithf "Unrecognised"
```

Your `x |> List.map parse` has a type `float list list` but on other branch your expression has a type `float`. Am I correct that you tried to return `float list`?

Comment: Thanks, and noted about the type annotations.  In the example above however, I need to return a float list list as the expressiontree is nested to a depth of 2.  So I need `[[ 1.0; 2.0; 3.0 ]; [1.0; 2.0; 3.0 ]; [1.0; 2.0; 3.0] ]` rather than the `[1.0; 2.0; 3.0; 1.0; 2.0; 3.0; 1.0; 2.0; 3.0]` your code gives.  Of course, if the return I got was nested to a depth of three, I'd need to return float list list list.

Comment: In that case I wouldn't try to write recursive function because you are only allowing to pass particular shape of Return type to your function and for other cases you are just throwing exception. If you want to support only 2-depth expression trees just pattern match to them explicitly.

Comment: Thanks Bartek.  I clearly haven't understood enough of the implications around recursive functions yet to know when they are (not) useful.