# How Can I Convert a Binary Expression Tree from a String to a Nested List?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, expression-trees

My original problem was understanding what it was I was even trying to do. I didn't really know *how* to search for help because I didn't really understand this is what I was trying to do. I've explained in detail in my answer *what* I did, and how I did it. I've also posted my code.

I spent a while prototyping in PowerShell before I built it in C#. I hope this is helpful for others.

### Question :

How can I convert a string like `"(Foo1 && Bar1 && (Foo2 || Bar2) && (Foo3 || Foo4))"` to a list like this:

```cs
[
   ["Foo1", "Bar1", "Foo2", "Foo3"],
   ["Foo1", "Bar1", "Foo2", "Foo4"],
   ["Foo1", "Bar1", "Bar2", "Foo3"],
   ["Foo1", "Bar1", "Bar2", "Foo4"]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Converting a String Representation of a Binary Expression Tree to a Nested String List of All Possible Combinations

I was trying to build a class that would allow me to convert a Binary Expression Tree in string format (see input examples below) to a nested list of all possible combination of values. At the beginning of this, I was not aware this was a Binary Expression Tree, and thus hadn't really known how to find what I was looking for.

> **Note :** *I'm **not** formally trained in CS nor did I receive a formal education in programming. I came up in IT as a Systems Admin who, aside from a brief period of programming in C++ as a teen, and years of HTML/CSS had never really messed with compiled software. I wrote a lot of scripts and spent about five years master PowerShell -- which is still where I'm the most comfortable. Most of my prototyping for this was done in PowerShell (7.1.3).*

You can see [My Code](https://github.com/rbleattler/BinaryExpressionTreeToStringCollection) on github.

## Input examples

### Example 1

```c
"(param_1 && param_2 && (param_3 || param_4) && (param_5 || param_6 || param_7))"
```

### Example 2

```c
"((param1 && (param2 || param3 || param4)) && param5)"
```

### Example 3

```c
"(param1 || (param2 && param3 && param4 && (param5 || param6 || param7)))"
```

## Expected Outputs

### Example 1

```json
[
    ["param_1","param_2","param_3","param_5"],
    ["param_1","param_2","param_3","param_6"],
    ["param_1","param_2","param_3","param_7"],
    ["param_1","param_2","param_4","param_5"],
    ["param_1","param_2","param_4","param_6"],
    ["param_1","param_2","param_4","param_7"]
]
```

### Example 2

```json
[
    [
        ["param1", "param2", "param5"],
        ["param1", "param3", "param5"], 
        ["param1", "param4", "param5"]
    ]
]
```

### Example 3

```json
[
    [
        ["param1"],
        ["param2", "param3", "param4", "param5"],
        ["param2", "param3", "param4", "param6"],
        ["param2", "param3", "param4", "param7"]
    ]
]
```

There were a few pain points along the way -- places where I got stuck and wound up repeating work as I tried to solve my way through it.

### Converting the string to a Binary Expression Tree

Before I found what I was looking for in a library, I'd spent a considerable amount of time building a parser to convert the string into a Binary Expression Tree.

#### Solution

Eventually I found NRECO's [LambdaParser library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NReco.LambdaParser/) ([github](https://github.com/nreco/lambdaparser)), and that took away a lot of the stress of doing that (even though I'm pretty sure what I'd built was complete in that sense).

## Unexpected Edge Cases

While it may seem trivial and obvious, I kept running into issues when walking the tree to build my lists.

### Multiple Like Expressions in the Left Member

Initially I'd not accounted for situations where the left member contained multiple like expressions (*ie* "this AND that AND that too"), which resulted in building incomplete lists.

### Node Contains No Member Expression (?)

I thought I'd completed the tool. I got a list of possible expressions (beyond the handful I'd been testing with), and... it imploded. I found that I'd not accounted for situations where the currently processing node contained two Binary Expressions. (whereas I'd built it thus far under the impression that one side or the other was *always* a Member Expression)

Once I got to this problem, I'd realized what was wrong and had already spent so much time with this thing I knew *what* needed to be done, just not quite how I was going to do it.

#### Solution

When presented with one of these nodes I had to create two diverging paths based on whichever expression was *closest* to the next member expression in depth. From there it will create two paths, process downward on the opposite node until reaching the "bottom". The we can add every iteration of each path to the primary output. Given that this function is recursive, it *shouldn't* matter how many times this occurs

> **NOTE :** *In my solution, when it encounters a **Binary Expression** containing no Member Expressions it **does** currently still assume that one of the two expressions will be a Member Expression. That said, if I understand the nature of this type of expression, I don't think this should be an issue*

> **Note :** I had found a few references, including this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37343467/parsing-expression-tree-into-nested-lists) regarding doing something similar F#, but I couldn't seem to apply this to my problem.

### Key Takeaway

For me this was a really useful learning experience for me in which I was presented with a real world problem involving a core data structure. Since I've no real background with (programming) algorithms, or data structures this taught me a lot and despite it being a huge PITA, it taught me a lot about how to solve these types of problems in the future. I'd encourage anyone to try to build this yourself if you have the time. Thanks for reading.